# Rails ancestry gem scoping problems -- How do I limit number of children retrieved while getting all the children of those children?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ancestry

I'm using ancestry 2.1.0 (latest release) in Rails 4 and I'm trying to retrieve the first 10 children of an object along with all of the children of those 10 children. In other words, if I have an object with 30 children, and each child has x number of children, I want to get only the first 10 children with x grandchildren for each child.

My attempt:

```
post = Post.includes(:datum).find(clicked_id)
    nodes = post.subtree(:to_depth => 1).limit(10)


    nodes.each do |node|
      nodes.push(node.childen)
    end
```

When I try this in the console it says that there is no "children" method for  post.

Comment: There's a `descendants` method which fetches records more deeply. What you have here generates an extraordinary number of queries, so you'll want to be careful about aggressively calling `find` and `children`. Are you sure you're added `has_ancestry` to your `Post` model?

Comment: Yes, has_ancestry is included in the Post model. The "nodes = post.subtree(:to_depth => 1).limit(10)" query works just fine, its the "nodes.push(post.children)" query that doesn't work. I tried calling find to force rails to evaluate the query thinking my issue might have been with relations, but that didn't work.

Comment: If you're getting a Post model, then `children` should work. Why not `to_depth: 2`? I'm also completely confused why you're doing a `Post.find` on an `id` that comes back from a fetch which *should* return Posts in the first place.

Comment: If I use to_depth:2 then I can't limit the number of first level children. I need to limit the number of posts at depth 1 but still get all the depth 2 posts for the limited set. I edited the post to take out Post.find -- you're right it wasn't doing anything, it was just my way to check to see if it was a relations problem.

Comment: Make sure that `node` is the right type. If it is there's no reason `children` should not be defined. What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: node is an active record relation. This is the exact error message I get in my console when I run the same code: "Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."ancestry" = '1'
NoMethodError: undefined method `children' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f9f00f6e018>
from /Users/drewlilley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in `method_missing'"

Comment: Looks like you're calling the method on an aggregate (relationship) rather than an individual Post. Have a closer look at the structure `subtree` returns.